# how to add super CSS class to css classes?

Tags: css

i have a progressbar in primefaces that i want change the color . I can change it with this code and its changed to yelew color :

```
.ui-progressbar .ui-widget-header {
    background: yellow !important;
}
```

the problem that i want change it dynamically with a new styleclass that i want create for:

i tryed this code but didnt work :

```
.myclass2 .ui-progressbar .ui-widget-header {
        background: yellow ;
```

thats the code of the progress bar :

```
                <p:progressBar value="100}" labelTemplate="{value}%" displayOnly="true" styleClass="ui-widget-header yellow" />
```

but didnt work whats the good syntaxe to use ??

Comment: Stop using `!important`.

Comment: i stoped using !important